# Seek backwards a text file in Qt5/C++ (tail a file)

Tags: c++, qt, file, memory-mapped-files

I need to create the Qt5/C++ equivalent of 'tail -5 myfile' (without using a shell command.  I found a couple of stackoverflow references to seeking X bytes before end of file and then reading forward, but I'm hoping for something better.

Is there a better/faster way with available Qt functions, or perhaps memory mapping (part of) the file?  (the file in question can be HUGE, so this has to be relatively memory efficient)

Comment: So what are you trying to do? You want to read the last N bytes of a file? `QFile` has a seek function.

Comment: What do you mean "something better"? You read the file in blocks of some size even if you do `head -5`, the buffering may just be invisible to you,, hidden kn library and the OS. When reading backwards, you just need to do this yourself.

Comment: I am trying to read the last 5 lines of a text file (\n line seperators).  The linux command 'tail' shows the last X lines of a text file.

Answer (score 5):

As `sashoalm` said, use `seek()` method. For example:

```
QElapsedTimer tmr;
tmr.start();
QFile file("path");
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
qint64 num = 10;
qint64 fileSize = file.size();
qDebug() << fileSize;
file.seek(fileSize - num);
qDebug() << file.read(num);
qDebug() <<"reading took" << tmr.elapsed()<< "ms";
file.close();
}
```

Perfomance:

I have next output with file `~11 Gb`.

```
size  11768585585 
"???G?t??" 
reading took 23 ms
```

Program didn't increase `RAM` usage. For small files `(~1Gb)` I had `0ms`. I think that it is normal speed.

Edit:

The way to do something like tail utility with Qt can be next. I don't convinced that this way very correct and have big perfomance, but it is better than read all file and parse it. We can't read file from end to begin with some magic `readLineFromEnd()` method, so try to use next:

```
QElapsedTimer tmr;
tmr.start();
QFile file("path");
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    file.seek(file.size()-1);
    int count = 0;
    int lines = 5;
    while ( (count < lines) && (file.pos() > 0) )
    {
        QString ch = file.read(1);
        file.seek(file.pos()-2);
        if (ch == "\n")
            count++;
    }
    qDebug() << file.readAll();

qDebug() <<"reading took" << tmr.elapsed()<< " ms";
file.close();
}
```

Output for `8Kb` txt file:

```
reading took 2 ms .
```

Output for `~8Mb` txt file(it is a log file):

```
reading took 1 ms
```

Yes, it has lower perfomance, but it is complicate task. Interesting how much time need tail utility to do this, but anyways 1 and 2 ms are (maybe) good result.

Comment: This doesn't read lines (not the question refers to 'tail' - which is a linux command to print out the last X lines of a file).  This just reads n bytes

Comment: @GenerationDSystems see my edit please, maybe it will be useful.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem very elegant...how about a memory mapped file?  How about reading a block into a QString and using indexOf for newlines, etc.

Comment: @GenerationDSystems my approach it is what you want, but with size of block equals 1. If you think that reading block and parsing it can be elegant then try to do this. Maybe I don't right, but I think that it is not so good. Suppose that you have block with 8 \n , then you need write code which can take only 5 last(and so on, code should predict anything). I don't think that this parsing can be elegant, maybe it is more efficiency(maybe), but not elegant. Anyways code in my answer contains all needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Kosovan's answer is flawed, it accidently reads the last two characters of the line previous to the first line you want.  Here's the corrected code:

```
QElapsedTimer tmr;
tmr.start();
QFile file("path");
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    file.seek(file.size()-1);
    int count = 0;
    int lines = 5;
    while ( (count < lines) && (file.pos() > 0) )
    {
        QString ch = file.read(1);
        file.seek(file.pos()-2);
        if (ch == "\n")
            count++;
    }
    file.seek(previous_debug_file.pos()+2);
    qDebug() << file.readAll();

qDebug() <<"reading took" << tmr.elapsed()<< " ms";
file.close();
}
```